# What is the error in this connection string in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, connection-string

I have the following connection string

```
<add name="portal_ConnSql" connectionString="Data Source=GFO-SQL03;Initial Catalog=PortalDB_V2;uid=Portal_Usr;Password=20!!P0rt@!"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The code to get the Key :

```
Public Sub New()
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("EPER_ConnSql").ToString()
    conn = New SqlConnection(connString)

    portalConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("portal_ConnSql").ToString()
    portalConn = New SqlConnection(portalConnString)

    cmd = New SqlCommand

End Sub
Public Shared ReadOnly Property PortalConnectionStr() As String
    Get
        Return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("portal_ConnSql").ConnectionString
    End Get
End Property
```

I got the following error  :

```
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) 
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) 
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) 
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) 
at util.getPortalRefelralCode(String referalCode) in E:\sites\EPER EN\App_Code\util.vb:line 280 
at Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\sites\EPER EN\Test.aspx.vb:line 9 
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Where is the code to get and use the key?

Comment: @nmat please check the question updates

Comment: What error message? Where?

Comment: @SysDragon the error message is :  Exception Description : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.\nSource File : \nLine : 0

Comment: Does the EPER_ConnSql connection string work?

Comment: EPER_ConnSql, yes it is